# Shrinking elements with padding

Tags: css

Given an element with a certain left and right padding, it seems to not be possible to set its width to anything less than the sum of the two.

A quick Google search would have you believe salvation lies with the `box-sizing` property, and while that would indeed make sense (given how the box model works), it surprisingly enough does not change anything.

What have I missed?

In [this minimal working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6yjb75hh/1/), the red element should not be visible. I'd like to avoid cluttering the HTML with extraneous elements if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The red area appear because of the text inside it. you have 2 options either to remove the text or to set the font size to 0 like that:

```
#c
{
    background: red;
    width: 0em;
    font-size: 0em;
}
```

Comment: That does indeed work, but I wish to still be able to display text inside the element. The whole point of having padding is to pad the content.